# .delay not working

Tags: jquery

I am relatively new to jQuery so this may be a beginners mistake, but for some reason I can't get the `.delay()` function to work.

The code I am working with is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                     
    $("div#main").css("opacity","0");  
    $("div#main").animate({opacity: 1}.delay(1000), 'slow');  
});
```

With the "jQuery 1.2.3 - New Wave Javascript" script

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a more complete example? ie...where you are storing your var of opactiy, all the src if it is a small block would be helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems. One is that there is no `delay` function in jQuery 1.2.3. You'll either need to include it as a plugin or update to the most recent version of jQuery. Assuming that you've done this, the other problem is that you're calling `delay` on a normal JavaScript object, and not a jQuery object. You should be getting an error from trying to call a non-existent function. So instead of this:

```
$("div#main").animate({opacity: 1}.delay(1000), 'slow');
```

Use this:

```
$("div#main").delay(1000).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
```

This inserts a one second delay in the animation queue that will be executed before the opacity animation is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code you're showing here. Did you place the whole thing in a document ready handler so that it will only execute when the DOM is ready for manipulation?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#main").css("opacity","0").delay(1000).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
});
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/cRqwd/ for a simple example of your code working.

---

**Edit:** I assume you're looking at this: http://allforeveryone.blogspot.com/2008/03/jquery-new-wave-javascript.html. In case you have not noticed, that is an *incredibly old* version of jQuery you're working with there. [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) was only introduced in version 1.4. Go to http://jquery.com to download the latest version.

Comment: Yeah it is, but when I put the .delay in front of the .animate it does not load at all.

Comment: @Chad You have to include more code in your question - as you can see, the code you gave works.

Comment: right, Sorry I just posted the full code. I have removed all the other javascript from the page(jquery lightbox) and made sure there wasn't any opacity codes in the css.